# Why I can`t use symbol in Rails 3 view Lazy Lookup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, localization

I have following table in view:

```
# views/students/index.html.haml
%table.table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th=t :first_name  # doesn`t work
      %th=t '.last_name' # works
  %tbody
    - @students.each do |s|
      %tr
        %td=s.first_name
        %td=s.last_name
```

This is my locales file:

```
pl:
  students:
    index:
      first_name: "Imię"
      last_name: "Nazwisko"
```

Is possible to use symbols instead of string '.first_name' ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work with `:'.first_name'` (I assume the "symbol" you are referring to is the period)